# PHP postgres Zend Framework Select query with WHERE 'AND' clause

Tags: php, zend-framework

Ok Im still new to Zend, and trying to find how the ORM works in general for it, seems to be posing a difficult task (anyone know where they have a specific document for it). That aside what I am trying to do is take an existing query and add a "AND" clause to it. Just not sure how to go about doing that, as the examples I have found else where dont look like this one, and I'd rather avoid breakage on this

```
$select = $this->select()
            ->from('offer_term')
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->joinUsing('term_mapping', 'term_id')
            ->where('promo_id = ?', $promo_id);
        return $this->fetchAll($select);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is really easy once you start understand how Zend_db works.

your query:

```
$select = $this->select()
            ->from('offer_term')
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->joinUsing('term_mapping', 'term_id')
            ->where('promo_id = ?', $promo_id);
        return $this->fetchAll($select);
```

you are already using the `select()` object for performing the query, so try refactoring to something like this(I'll include how do it with a conditional as well):

```
$select = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$select->from('offer_term');//if query is inside of a DbTable model the from() can be omitted
$select->joinUsing('term_mapping', 'term_id');
$select->where('promo_id = ?', $promo_id);//Every time you add a where(), select() adds the param using the AND operator
$select->where('something_new = ?', $new_param);//if you need to add a param using OR you can use the orWhere() method.
if (TRUE) {
    $select->orWhere('something = ?',$parameter);//This will add an OR WHERE to the query if the condition is true.
}
return $this->fetchAll($select);
```

Adding an *AND* in a `select()` query is done just by adding another `where()` to the chain. This can be done by chaining as your original query does or by using separate statements as I have done. If you need to use the *OR* operator in `select()` query you can use the `orWhere()` method.

You can mix chaining and separate statements as needed, which makes adding a conditional pretty easy.

**NOTE:** Zend_Db is not an ORM, it is an implementation of The table gateway and table row patterns (I hope I got the names correct). So please do not expect full ORM functionality.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$select = $this->select()
    ->from('offer_term')
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->joinUsing('term_mapping', 'term_id')
    ->where('promo_id = ?', $promo_id);
    ->where('name = ?', $name); // WHERE promo_id = $promo_id AND name = $name
return $this->fetchAll($select);
```

And remember to using [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.where).

Comment: don't suppose theres a way to append to the query in the event of a an if-else clause. Say this is being instantiated via a function and in some cases cause this is old code and it'd be hard to track everything down right now, so with that function I want to do `$extra = null` so by default it will work as it is now, but in the event I pass `$extra` I want to append the additional clause to the query, whats the proper way to do that?