# zend framework where statement in query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, where-clause

How can I use And/or in mysql queries using php and zend framework.for now I am using this :

```
    $db=Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $select=new Zend_Db_Select($db);
    $select->from('users','*');
    $select->joinInner('rest', 'users.repository = rest.id',array('username'));
    $select->where('username='.$rest.' and sold=0');
    return $db->fetchAll($select);
```

is that the correct way ? if not what is the correct way?

Answer (score 3):

You can add `AND`'s to your query by calling `where()` multiple times:

```
$select->where('this = ?', 'myValue')
       ->where('that = ?', 'myValue2');
```

This will translate into:

```
... WHERE this = 'myValue' AND that = 'myValue2'
```

To add one or more `OR`'s to your query, use `orWhere()`:

```
$select->where('this = ?', 'myValue')
       ->orWhere('that = ?', 'myValue2');
```

This will translate into:

```
... WHERE this = 'myValue' OR that = 'myValue2'
```

**Note**

Be sure to use the `?` placeholder syntax as it is an easy way to prevent SQL injections.

Answer (score 2):

That's one way, but you should be using ? placeholders for variables to protect against SQL injection:

```
$select=new Zend_Db_Select($db);
$select->from('users','*');
$select->joinInner('rest', 'users.repository = rest.id', array('username'));
$select->where('username = ? and sold=0', $rest);
```

(do the same for 'sold' if this sometimes also comes from a PHP variable.)

You can also chain together where clauses with multiple `where()` calls or `orWhere()` if you want or instead of and:

```
$select=new Zend_Db_Select($db);
$select->from('users','*');
$select->joinInner('rest', 'users.repository = rest.id', array('username'));
$select->where('username = ?' $rest);
$select->where('sold = ?', 0);
```

Since Zend_Db_Select uses a fluent influence you can also write it like this:

```
$select=new Zend_Db_Select($db);
$select->from('users','*')
       ->joinInner('rest', 'users.repository = rest.id', array('username'))
       ->where('username = ?' $rest)
       ->where('sold = ?', 0);
```

Comment: thank you all but is what about or ? for example i want this where(fname='ggg' and (post > 5 || thanks>30 ) and age=10)

Comment: easiest way would be `$select->where('fname = ?', 'ggg')->where('post > 5 OR thanks > 30);`

Comment: thanks but there is possible risk on variable risk and thanks for sql injection. as you see they are passed like a string while they are variables

Comment: Then use `$select->where('fname = ?', 'ggg')->where('post > ? OR thanks > ?, array(5, 30));` replacing ggg, 5 and 30 with the PHP variables.

Answer (score 0):

The following will fix your question, see [PHP postgres Zend Framework Select query with WHERE 'AND' clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11268303/1145086) for a more complete writeup on how where() and orWhere() work.

```
$db=Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $select=new Zend_Db_Select($db);
    $select->from('users','*');
    $select->joinInner('rest', 'users.repository = rest.id',array('username'));
    $select->where('username= ?',$rest);//multiple where() will use AND operator in query
    $select->where('sold = ?', 0);//if you need the OR operator use the orWhere() method
    return $db->fetchAll($select);
```

To answer about the question marks (Excerpt from manual):

`fetchAll($select, $value)//most of the Zend_Db methods follow this API`

> **fetchAll() method:**
>   The first argument to this method is a string containing a SELECT
>   statement. Alternatively, the first argument can be an object of class
>   Zend_Db_Select. The Adapter automatically converts this object to a
>   string representation of the SELECT statement

ie (? is a place holder for $value):
`$select->where('id = ?', $id);`
`$select->orWhere('age > ?', $age);`

You are currently using the old syntax, while it will still work it has been deprecated.