# zend unable to display multiple diff records in phtml

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
   $where = array('status' => 1);
$this->view->active = $user->fetchAll($where);
$where1 = array('status' => 0);
$this->view->inactive = $user->fetchAll($where1);
```

in view.phtml

i have these two foreach

```
foreach($this->active as $active){
    echo $active->uid;
    echo $active->uname;
}

foreach($this->inactive as $inactive_va){
    echo $inactive_va->uid;
    echo $inactive_va->uname;
}
```

Above code returns only active records  for both inactive and inactive. what would i have to change on these.

Comment: have you tried the `print_r($this->active);` what is it return?

Comment: It is not clear what is wrong here. Are you saying that you are getting same list of users twice and those users are from list of active users or foreach with inactive users returns nothing and you are getting output of the first foreach only? Are you sure you have users with status =0 in database?

Comment: when i put print_r, it displaying same records for both, second one " $where1 = array('status' => 0);
$this->view->inactive = $user->fetchAll($where1); "  not applied. but in foreach i am using the  " inactive " only, for this array, active records are displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the `?` placeholder syntax to make your `WHERE` clause correct:

```
$where = array('status = ?' => 1);
$where1 = array('status = ?' => 0);
```

However, please note that supplying a `WHERE` clause directly to `fetchAll()` is deprecated. See the **warning** at the [Zend_Db_Table documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.fetch-all). It is better to modify your query with a `Zend_Db_Table_Select` object.

Your first query would then look like:

```
$user->fetchAll(
    $user->select()->where('status = ?', 1);
);
```

Comment: for multiple and cond how ?

Comment: ->where("price = ?",$price)
->where('product_name = ?', $prod); please confirm this

Comment: OR this $select = $db->select()
             ->from('products',
                    array('product_id', 'product_name', 'price'))
             ->where('price > ?', $minimumPrice)
             ->where('price < ?', $maximumPrice);

Comment: Exactly. Both should be correct. See my answer here as well on how to combine multiple `WHERE` clauses with `AND` or `OR`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11273598/1255724